# line break within Html.Encode & String.Join

Tags: html, asp.net, line-breaks, html-encode

I have the following line of code.

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join(", ", item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())) %>
```

Would it be possible to somehow replace the comma with a line break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

`<%= Html.Encode(string.Join("***", item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())).Replace("***", "<br />") %>`

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work fine without encoding the string and joining on `"<br/>"` as follows.  Depending on your Array data you might need to encode that specifically, but you don't want to encode any HTML syntax you would be using for your join character.

```
<%= string.Join("<br/>", [Array]) %>
```

**Note**: the new ASP.Net 4.0 code expression syntax `"<%: %>"` html encodes the contents of the block by default so if you were using that you'd have to use the .Replace("***",`"<br\>`) method suggested by RememberME.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Environment.NewLine?

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())) %>
```

or "\r\n"

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join("\r\n", item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())) %>
```

**EDIT TO ADD**

If the companies are separated by space, the try joining the array by a space character

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join(" ", item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())) %>
```

**EDIT TO ADD 2**

Join by a html line break

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join("<br/>", item.company1.companies.Select(x => x.company_name).ToArray())) %>
```

Comment: maybe item.company1.companies is empty

Comment: No.  I see the list of companies.  They're just separated by a space.

Comment: Then join by space, have you tried? or maybe it is a unicode unrecognized character... i'm just speculating in the case the character is not a space

Comment: When I join by "\r\n" or Environment.NewLine they show as joined by a space.  I would like when they are displayed for there to be a line break between each company.  If not, I will leave them separated by commas, but I think a line break would be much more user friendly.

Comment: If you want to "display" them, try joining with a "<br/>" that way, after each company, it willl break

Comment: that's the quick and dirty... it would be better a list or something like that

Comment: Putting "<br />" inside the Join displayed the companies with "<br />" between them rather than a line break.